# HADOOP : java.io.IOException

Tags: hadoop

Checked almost everywhere and this issue seems to persist.

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hdoop/dfsdata/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hdoop/dfsdata/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

The above is my hdfs-site.xml configuration.

When I try to format namenode

I get the Java:IO Exception error.

Any help to this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your hdfs-site.xml has the same property dfs.data.dir for both name node and data node directories. It needs to be dfs.namenode.name.dir for namenode and dfs.datanode.data.dir for data node.
Please refer here for more details on the configurations available in hdfs:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Check here on how to set up apache hadoop as a single node cluster :
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html